# Calculate Start and End of Fiscal Period Weeks

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have a calendar table established (thank you, [Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.Dim_Calendar', N'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.Dim_Calendar

SET DATEFIRST 7, LANGUAGE us_english;
DECLARE @StartDate date = '19210101', 
        @Years     int  = 200;
;WITH seq(n) AS 
(
  SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT n + 1 FROM seq
  WHERE n < DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, DATEADD(YEAR, @Years, @StartDate))
),
d(d) AS 
(
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n - 1, @StartDate) FROM seq
),
src AS
(
  SELECT
    TheDate         = CONVERT(date,       d),
    CalendarDay          = DATEPART(DAY,       d),
    CalendarDayName      = DATENAME(WEEKDAY,   d),
    CalendarWeek         = DATEPART(WEEK,      d),
    CalendarISOWeek      = DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,  d),
    CalendarDayOfWeek    = DATEPART(WEEKDAY,   d),
    CalendarMonth        = DATEPART(MONTH,     d),
    CalendarMonthName    = DATENAME(MONTH,     d),
    CalendarQuarter      = DATEPART(QUARTER,   d),
    CalendarYear         = DATEPART(YEAR,      d),
    CalendarFirstOfMonth = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(d), MONTH(d), 1),
    CalendarLastOfYear   = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(d), 12, 31),
    CalendarDayOfYear    = DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, d)
  FROM d
),
dim AS
(
  SELECT
    TheDate, 
    CalendarDay,
    CalendarDaySuffix        = CONVERT(char(2), CASE WHEN CalendarDay / 10 = 1 THEN 'th' ELSE 
                            CASE RIGHT(CalendarDay, 1) WHEN '1' THEN 'st' WHEN '2' THEN 'nd' 
                            WHEN '3' THEN 'rd' ELSE 'th' END END),
    CalendarDayName,
    CalendarDayOfWeek,
    CalendarDayOfWeekInMonth = CONVERT(tinyint, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                            (PARTITION BY CalendarFirstOfMonth, CalendarDayOfWeek ORDER BY TheDate)),
    CalendarDayOfYear,
    IsWeekend           = CASE WHEN CalendarDayOfWeek IN (CASE @@DATEFIRST 
                            WHEN 1 THEN 6 WHEN 7 THEN 1 END,7) 
                            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    CalendarWeek,
    CalendarISOweek,
    CalendarFirstOfWeek      = DATEADD(DAY, 1 - CalendarDayOfWeek, TheDate),
    CalendarLastOfWeek       = DATEADD(DAY, 6, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - CalendarDayOfWeek, TheDate)),
    CalendarWeekOfMonth      = CONVERT(tinyint, DENSE_RANK() OVER 
                            (PARTITION BY CalendarYear, CalendarMonth ORDER BY CalendarWeek)),
    CalendarMonth,
    CalendarMonthName,
    CalendarFirstOfMonth,
    CalendarLastOfMonth      = MAX(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY CalendarYear, CalendarMonth),
    CalendarFirstOfNextMonth = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CalendarFirstOfMonth),
    CalendarLastOfNextMonth  = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 2, CalendarFirstOfMonth)),
    CalendarQuarter,
    CalendarFirstOfQuarter   = MIN(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY CalendarYear, CalendarQuarter),
    CalendarLastOfQuarter    = MAX(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY CalendarYear, CalendarQuarter),
    CalendarYear,
    CalendarISOYear          = CalendarYear - CASE WHEN CalendarMonth = 1 AND CalendarISOWeek > 51 THEN 1 
                            WHEN CalendarMonth = 12 AND CalendarISOWeek = 1  THEN -1 ELSE 0 END,      
    CalendarFirstOfYear      = DATEFROMPARTS(CalendarYear, 1,  1),
    CalendarLastOfYear,
    IsLeapYear          = CONVERT(bit, CASE WHEN (CalendarYear % 400 = 0) 
                            OR (CalendarYear % 4 = 0 AND CalendarYear % 100 <> 0) 
                            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Has53Weeks          = CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEK,     CalendarLastOfYear) = 53 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    Has53ISOWeeks       = CASE WHEN DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, CalendarLastOfYear) = 53 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    MMYYYY              = CONVERT(char(2), CONVERT(char(8), TheDate, 101))
                          + CONVERT(char(4), CalendarYear),
    Style101            = CONVERT(char(10), TheDate, 101),
    Style103            = CONVERT(char(10), TheDate, 103),
    Style112            = CONVERT(char(8),  TheDate, 112),
    Style120            = CONVERT(char(10), TheDate, 120)       
  FROM src
)

SELECT DateKey = CAST(FORMAT(TheDate, 'yyyyMMdd') as int),
        TheDate, 
        CalendarDay,
        CalendarDaySuffix,
        CalendarDayName,
        CalendarDayOfWeek,
        CalendarDayOfWeekInMonth,
        CalendarDayOfYear,
        IsWeekend,
        CalendarWeek,
        CalendarISOweek,
        CalendarFirstOfWeek,
        CalendarLastOfWeek,
        CalendarWeekOfMonth,
        CalendarMonth,
        CalendarMonthName,
        CalendarFirstOfMonth,
        CalendarLastOfMonth,
        CalendarFirstOfNextMonth,
        CalendarLastOfNextMonth,
        CalendarQuarter,
        CalendarFirstOfQuarter,
        CalendarLastOfQuarter,
        CalendarYear,
        CalendarISOYear,
        CalendarFirstOfYear,
        CalendarLastOfYear,
        IsLeapYear,
        Has53Weeks,
        Has53ISOWeeks,
        MMYYYY,
        Style101,
        Style103,
        Style112,
        Style120
INTO dbo.Dim_Calendar
FROM dim
  ORDER BY TheDate
  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

I'm setting up my Fiscal Year columns in a separate stored proc:

```
;WITH
LastFridayInOctober AS(
    SELECT YEAR(TheDate) 'TheYear',
            CalendarMonth,
            CalendarDayOfWeek,
            MAX(CalendarDayOfWeekInMonth) 'LastFriday'
    FROM dbo.Dim_Calendar
    WHERE CalendarMonth = 10
        AND CalendarDayOfWeek = 6
    GROUP BY YEAR(TheDate),
                CalendarMonth,
                CalendarDayOfWeek
),

FYSetup AS(
    SELECT TheDate,
            LastDayOfFiscalYear,
            EndOfFiscalYear,
            FirstDayOfFiscalYear
    FROM (SELECT DD.TheDate,
                    DATEADD(day, 1, DD.TheDate) 'LastDayOfFiscalYear',
                    YEAR(DD.TheDate) 'EndOfFiscalYear',
                    YEAR(DD.TheDate) + 1 'NextFiscalYear',
                    DATEADD(day, 2, DD.TheDate) 'FirstDayOfFiscalYear'
            FROM dbo.Dim_Calendar DD
                INNER JOIN LastFridayInOctober LFIO ON DD.CalendarYear = LFIO.TheYear
                    AND DD.CalendarMonth = LFIO.CalendarMonth
                    AND DD.CalendarDayOfWeek = LFIO.CalendarDayOfWeek
                    AND DD.CalendarDayOfWeekInMonth = LFIO.LastFriday
        ) A
),

FiscalYears AS(
    SELECT YEAR(DD.TheDate) + 1 'FiscalYear',
            DATEADD(day, 2, DD.TheDate) 'FirstDayOfFiscalYear',
            T.LastDayOfFiscalYear
    FROM dbo.Dim_Calendar DD
        INNER JOIN LastFridayInOctober LFIO ON DD.CalendarYear = LFIO.TheYear
            AND DD.CalendarMonth = LFIO.CalendarMonth
            AND DD.CalendarDayOfWeek = LFIO.CalendarDayOfWeek
            AND DD.CalendarDayOfWeekInMonth = LFIO.LastFriday
        LEFT OUTER JOIN FYSetup T ON YEAR(DD.TheDate) + 1 = T.EndOfFiscalYear
),

Periods AS(
    SELECT top (13)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) Period
    FROM syscolumns
),

PeriodStartEndDates AS (
    SELECT -- top (13)
        FY.FiscalYear,
        Period, 
        DATEADD(DAY, 28 *  (Period - 1) , FY.FirstDayOfFiscalYear) PeriodStartDate,
        IIF(Period = 13, FY.LastDayOfFiscalYear, DATEADD(DAY, 28 *  Period, FY.FirstDayOfFiscalYear)) PeriodEndDate
        -- IIF(Period = 13, FY.LastDayOfFiscalYear, DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(week, 4, PeriodStartDate))) PeriodEndDate
    FROM Periods CROSS JOIN FiscalYears FY
),

Days as (
    SELECT 
        TOP (
            SELECT DATEDIFF(D, MIN(PeriodStartDate), MAX(PeriodEndDate)) 
            FROM PeriodStartEndDates
        ) -- How high we want to count
        DATEADD(
            D, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) - 1, -- ROW_NUMBER is 1 Based, so subtract 1
            (SELECT MIN(PeriodStartDate) FROM PeriodStartEndDates)
        ) AS TheDate
    FROM
        sys.columns a CROSS JOIN sys.columns b -- something with a lot of rows

),

Segment AS (
    SELECT
        FiscalYear
        ,Period FiscalPeriod
        ,DATEDIFF(WEEK, MIN(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY FiscalYear), TheDate) + 1 FiscalWeek 
        ,DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY FiscalYear), TheDate ) + 1 FiscalDay
        ,DATEDIFF(WEEK, MIN(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY FiscalYear, Period), TheDate) + 1 PeriodWeek
        ,'' StartOfFiscalWeek   -- NEED TO CALCULATE THIS
        ,'' EndOfFiscalWeek -- NEED TO CALCULATE THIS
        ,DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY FiscalYear, Period), TheDate ) + 1 PeriodDay
        ,MIN(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY FiscalYear, Period) FirstOfPeriod
        ,MAX(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY FiscalYear, Period) EndOfPeriod
        ,MIN(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY FiscalYear) StartOfFiscalYear
        ,MAX(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY FiscalYear) EndOfFiscalYear
        ,TheDate
    FROM
        Days JOIN PeriodStartEndDates ON TheDate BETWEEN PeriodStartDate AND PeriodEndDate

)

-- get the fiscal details
SELECT TheDate,
        FiscalYear,
        StartofFiscalYear,
        EndOfFiscalYear,
        FiscalPeriod,
        FirstOfPeriod,
        EndOfPeriod,
        FiscalWeek,
        FiscalDay,
        PeriodWeek,
        StartOfFiscalWeek,
        EndOfFiscalWeek,
        PeriodDay
FROM Segment
```

however I am not able to properly calculate the StartOf**Fiscal**Week and EndOf**Fiscal**Week (in the SEGMENT CTE).  I know it can be done, as I've done it before, but I've since lost that small piece of code.  Could some generous soul please lend a hand with this?

EDIT: I mistakenly stated "Period" when I meant "Fiscal" (StartOfFiscalWeel, EndOfFiscalWeek).  My apologies for any confusion this caused.  That being said, I have been able to use these functions to get the results I want, however when I attempt to run them in the SEGMENT CTE, I get the error "Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate."

```
MIN(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY FiscalYear, Period, DATEDIFF(WEEK, MIN(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY FiscalYear), TheDate) + 1) StartOfFiscalWeek --using calculation for FiscalWeek above
MAX(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY FiscalYear, Period, DATEDIFF(WEEK, MIN(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY FiscalYear), TheDate) + 1) EndOfFiscalWeek --using calculation for FiscalWeek above
```

Comment: Not sure why do you have nested window function. Shouldn't it just simply `MIN(TheDate) OVER (PARTITION BY FiscalPeriod, FiscalWeek) AS StartOfFiscalWeek ` ?

Comment: I **knew** it was something small like that, thank you.  Using your suggestion means moving the two new columns to the final SELECT statement (which is absolutely no big deal to me).  It's also shown me a few errors in my existing code.